# run xterm in background and exit

Tags: linux, bash, centos

From hostA (my Linux desktop), i ssh into hostB :

```
$ ssh hostB -X
$ (nohup xterm &)
$ (nohup xterm &)
$ exit   
## i don't get my prompt back
```

The xterm windows show up on hostA, but the terminal where i ssh into hostB doesn't return the prompt to me.

If i press Control+C, i get the prompt back, but the 2 xterm windows are closed.

Is there a way to run xterm in the background on another host and free up the original terminal?

Thanks

--Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -X option opens an X11 tunnel that runs through the ssh connection.
The tunnel can exist only as long as that ssh connection is open.

To do what you ask, you need to put ssh itself in the background without an interactive session involved.

There are at least two ways to do this.  One is to set up ssh connection sharing, which would allow you to open ssh in the background and then start multiple ssh sessions using the shared connection.  The ssh man page has details on this.

A simpler way would be to open ssh in the background just to open your two xterm sessons:

```
ssh -n -X hostB sh -c "xterm&xterm" &
```

The `-n` option tells ssh to not use stdin, which allows it to be placed in the background.   If ssh requires a password, you can omit the final `&`, enter the password, and then suspend it and put it in the background.

Comment: Thanks... Your solution worked for me.